# Electron execute javascript as very first thing on a page

Tags: javascript, electron

I have an electron app that opens a browser window with a certain web page.
Now, I want to execute some javascript on that page as the very first thing. But whatever I try, it always seems to run after some other JS on the web page I open.

I tried some events like `did-start-loading`, e.g.:

```
window.webContents.on('did-start-loading', () => {
  window.webContents.executeJavaScript("console.log('test');");
})
```

And by putting it directly after the `loadUrl`:

```
window.loadURL(url);
window.webContents.executeJavaScript(`console.log('test');`);
```

But in both cases `test` gets logged after some other javascript has ran on the page.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to run code in the main process. This is independent of the whatever happens in the renderer process. The page is loading in the renderer process and your did-start-loading is in the main process.

Comment: Well, the webContents.executeJavaScript api is meant to execute javascript in the renderer process from the main process. So I'm trying (from the main process) to execute some javascript on the page loaded by the renderer process, but before any of the existing javascript on that page runs.

Comment: Since you load an HTML file with scripts (your app usually), it will always run before this JavaScript code. So far my only idea is to use a blocking "sendSync" in the renderer + define a one time listener in the main to send data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include a preload script when you are creating the browser window.
Ex.

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  webPreferences: {
    preload: path.join(__dirname, 'renderer.js')
  }
});
```

Here the `renderer.js` is loaded before any other js files of that window.

From the source code -

```
     /**
     * Specifies a script that will be loaded before other scripts run in the page.
     * This script will always have access to node APIs no matter whether node
     * integration is turned on or off. The value should be the absolute file path to
     * the script. When node integration is turned off, the preload script can
     * reintroduce Node global symbols back to the global scope. See example .
     */
```

Let me  know if that works!

Comment: This doesn't let you run custom code like `executeJavaScript`. Use case: loading redux state from the main process for example.